# Builder pattern, augmenting return type?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to achieve compile time dependency validation via types. Ultimately this stems from using dependency injection, I'm getting tired of forgetting to add a dependency to a ServiceCollection. Let's say I have a builder of sorts, and I don't want to be able to add an item unless the things it depends on have already been added. I think this would be best illustrated by an example. I would like the following to fail:

```
var myBuilder = new MyBuilder(configuration)
    .AddMyServiceRequiresThing()        // dependency not satisfied, type error
    .AddMySecondServiceRequiresThing2() // dependency not satisfied, type error
    .AddMyThing()
    .AddMyThing2();
```

But I would like the following to succeed:

```
var myBuilder = MyBuilder(configuration)
    .AddThing()
    .AddMyServiceRequiresThing()    // dependency satisfied by AddThing()
    .AddThing2()
    .AddMyService2RequiresThing2(); // dependency satisfied by AddThing2()
```

And of course the following would also succeed:

```
var myBuilder = MyBuilder(configuration)
    .AddThing()
    .AddThing2()
    .AddMyServiceRequiresThing()    // dependency satisfied by AddThing()
    .AddMyService2RequiresThing2(); // dependency satisfied by AddThing2()
```

Essentially, when adding a "Thing", I want the type of the builder to be enhanced with the fact that it now provides that thing. But since "MyService" and "MyService2" may require different things, they can't just return the original builder type (no enhancement), and they can't just return what they require, as their requirements may be disjoint.

I've tried some generics magic, but have wound up nowhere. I can enforce this via runtime logic, but I want the type system to do it for me. Is c#'s type system strong enough to do this? All the information is available at compile time, I just don't know if it is possible to express.

Comment: "Is c#'s type system strong enough to do this?" And is there any other statically typed language this sort of thing works like you expect?

Comment: You could test for compile time checking the following way:
Bool variable initialized to false.
If you set that bool variable to true in Addthing(), and check for it in requiresthing(), if visual studio warns you that the section is never reached, you can infer, that it checks at compile time.
Additionally an Exception can take care of programming errors.

Comment: @WiktorZychla TBH I'm not familiar enough with stronger type systems like that of Haskell or (insert your favorite type system here) to know if this kind of pattern is possible or not.

Comment: @gismo that would only work if there were one and only one place a service or dependency were used. I have common services used across many projects. Each project has dependencies, sometimes the dependencies overlap and they use the same service.

Comment: @jrk doesnt the builder keep an internal state? Are there different initializations for different consumers?

Comment: @gismo: looks like it doesn't really matter whether it keeps an internal state or not. Note the OP asks for **compile time** validation, to keep "internal state" of an expression during compilation you'd have to augment the compilation pipeline which is not possible in C#.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure that it is even correct to look for such a feature. In examples you've provided it can be logical, but the `MyBuilder` object can be constructed and/or changed in any part(s) of the code that will not be tracked, or even in different threads that is not possible to track at compile time. 
Even in your sample it is not clear what is happening in Constructor of the `MyBuilder`. 
You can have also a method in the class that would update builder with its data and then you'll call the build functions

```
class Data1
{
    public void Update(MyBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.AddThing(); // or anything else
    }
}
```

And noone can be sure what exactly can be happened with the object in the function

If the amount or sequense of 'Things' doesn't matters maybe it would be better to have different builders including composite builders like

```
class Builder2
{
    public Builder2(MyBuilder builder)
    {
        _thing1 = builder.Thing1;
        AddThing2();
    }
    public XXX AddMyService2RequiresThing2()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Take a look how the Expression trees are implemented in C# it's sounds close to what you want. It allows you to build different Expressions/Delegated and has a good control on Compilation stage. Don't generalize thing you don't want to generalize

You can spread code to different objects that:
- Produced by Builder 
- Stored in Builder and provides additional data to it
- Has single 'Thing'/Block responcibility

```
public class Builder
{
    // Builder will have access to all fields of implementation 
    // which will be hidden from other part of code
    private ImplThinger1 ImplThinger1;
    // other Thinger implementations

    public IThinger1 AddThing1()
    {
        return ImplThinger1 ?? (ImplThinger1 = new ImplThinger1());
    }
}

public interface IThinger1
{
    void AddServiceReqThing1();
}

public class ImplThinger1 : IThinger1
{
    // accessible in builder and not outside 
    // if it's not created outside
    public Thing Data { get; }

    public void AddServiceReqThing1()
    {
        // Stuff
    }
}
```

At the end builder will have all the implementations that was added and it will be not possible to add Services directly to builder only through the `IThinger` interface implementations, that will be constructed using Builder, even if implementation will be created of `IThinger` will be created it woun't be injected into Builder

Comment: Adding things to the builder outside of the initial builder chain would be up to the builder to decide whether that thing has been added or not. That is ok.

Comment: Apparently SO doesn't allow lengthy edits of comments. And return saves the comment. TIL.

What I would like is if the providers modified the return type of the builder in such a way to say that the builder now offers that thing, whatever it may be. Consider an "AddMyCacheService" method, that would modify the builder to advertise that it now supports using IMyCacheService through DI. Any consumer of IMyCacheService shouldn't be able to add itself to the builder until that AddMyCacheService method has been called.

Comment: It sounds like better is to have a unit tests that running after each build and failes on incorrect settings.

Comment: Other way would be to move responsibility to other classes/ interfaces and operate with banch of sub builders. I'll add code to answer, because it's formatted better